# insufficient privileges error on oracle-sql

Tags: sql, oracle, privileges

I am a student, doing a project and one of the questions is to create a user APT1050. However, i am getting an error.

```
SQL> create user APT identified by abc password expire;
create user APT identified by abc password expire
                              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Help?

Comment: According to [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8003.htm) you must have the CREATE USER system privilege.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the user you're using doesn't have the `create user` system privilege. You should use a different user that has this privilege, such as `sys` or `system`.